# How to inspect the stack and IRP when breaking in a file system driver’s API?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I’m currently studying Windows kernel debugging.
I have created a sample program using GetVolumeInformation function and get all properties of all drivers, but then my mentor asked me to inspect the stack and the IRP (I/O Request Packet) when a breakpoint is hit in one of the file system driver’s API functions.
Is there a way to view the stack and the IRP in WinDbg?

I set up live debugging environment and placed the sample program on the debug target machine.
I found the following function using x (examine) command and I thought it looks like file system driver.

x nt!NtQueryVolumeInformationFile

I set bp on the above function but I could not see any IRPs…
I think I am not understanding how to see IRPs and File System drivers after all…

Comment: Are you sur you didn't more information than that because this is a rather tricky question: the IRP is actually built **inside** this function and sent to the relevant driver. If you step though the function you'll see the code reference a FILE_OBJECT, then a device object (for which the IRP is to be sent), then the IRP is built and send to the device stack, targeting a particular driver.